# Angular typesscript create pdf with pictures

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the problem that I create a pdf and the pictures in it are on top of each other, as in the picture

[image: img1]

Does anyone have any idea?

component.ts

```
downloadPdf() {
        const doc = new jsPDF();
        const head = [['Korrekte Antwort', 'Kind Antwort', 'Korrekt']];
        const body = [];
        if(this.exercise.words != undefined){
            for (let i = 0; i < this.exercise.pngs.length; i++) {            
                body.push([this.exercise.words[i], 'x', this.exercise.corrects[i] === true ? 'Richtig' : 'Falsch']);
            }
        }
        else{ 
            for (let i = 0; i < this.exercise.pngs.length; i++) {            
                body.push([this.schreibenExercise[i], 'x', this.exercise.corrects[i] === true ? 'Richtig' : 'Falsch']);
            }
        }
        autoTable(doc, {
            html: '#mytable',
            bodyStyles: {minCellHeight: 15},
            didDrawCell(data) {
                if (data.column.index === 1 && data.cell.section === 'body') {
                    const td = data.cell.raw as any;
                    const img = td.childNodes[0];
                    const height = data.cell.height - data.cell.padding('vertical');
                    const width = data.cell.width - data.cell.padding('horizontal');
                    const textPos = data.cell.getTextPos();
                    doc.addImage(img.currentSrc, textPos.x, textPos.y, width, height);
                    console.log(doc);
                }
            }
        });
        doc.save('Schnapp-L-Schreiben.pdf');
    }
```

component.html

```
<table id="mytable" style="display: none">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{result.student.name}}</th>
                    <th>{{result.testingDate | date: "dd.MM.yyyy"}}</th>
                    <th>{{result.testTemplate.title}}</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Korrekte Antwort</th>
                    <th>Kind Antwort</th>
                    <th>Korrekt</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let png of exercise.pngs; index as i">
                    <td > 
                        {{exercise.words == undefined ? schreibenExercise[i] : exercise.words[i]}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="{{png}}">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{exercise.corrects[i] === true ? 'Richtig' : 'Falsch'}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

but it should look like this

[image: img2]